# semantic ui library sidebar onhidden event not triggering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, semantic-ui

I am using semantic ui. I need to attach the callback function onHidden but the code below doesn't seem to work, the callback is never called.

What do i do?

```
$('.sidebar').sidebar('setting', 'onHidden', function(){
     console.log('on hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
$('.sidebar')
  .sidebar({
    onHide: function() {
      console.log('on hidden');
    }
});
```

Syntax is :

```
$('.your.element')
  .sidebar('behavior name', argumentOne, argumentTwo);
```

Comment: i solveed it, i am using angularjs, the issue is i was trying it in the run phase, if i put it in the controller it works.
Thanks